# NpgSQL Connect RDS AWS

Tags: c#, .net, postgresql, amazon-web-services, npgsql

I am learning RDS via Npgsql.
I could not find documentation telling me how to connect to AWS RDS PostgreSQL from C#.NET program running on premises. In other words I have a code running on a PC desktop or on-premises app server which wants to access a PostgreSQL database on RDS.
I get error "No Such Host is Known" from connection Open request.
I use the Endpoint string which I copied from AWS console.
Please point me to appropriate documentation or examples. I found some JDBC samples/documentation but it does not help me with C#.NET.
Thank you very much.

Comment: Please post your connection string as well as some sample code so we can understand what you're doing. You're basically support to put your RDS endpoint in your connection string with `Host=<server>`.

Comment: new NpgsqlConnection("Host=mypgrds.cdunzz1fuvf4.ap-southeast-2.rds.amazonaws.com;Username=usr;Password=xxx;Database=mydb;Ssl Mode=Disable;")

Comment: .Open method failed with "no such host". I want to establish if my connection string is valid and the problem is outside of my C# code, perhaps there is VPC or Elastic IP is required or firewall etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try connecting with [PostgreSQL's psql first](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html). You're right about this probably being some sort of network config issue (or just a badly-copied hostname).

Comment: thank you Shay. I will mark this as answered since you did not see anything wrong with my connection string. I will assume the problem is somewhere on the AWS side of things - networking, VPC, security, DNS, firewall etc. I just wanted to know if my connection string was the correct format for connecting from On-Premises PC/server into the AWS RDS PostgreSQL in a VPC (this is quite a mouthfull ! LOL).

Comment: The correct connection string for AWS RDS PostgreSQL when client is running outside of VPC is this: new NpgsqlConnection("Host=mypgrds.cdunzz1fuvf4.ap-southeast-2.rds.amazonaws.com;port=1234;Username=myuser;Password=mypassword;Database=mypgdb")

Comment: if it is not obvious to some, above I used a random sample AWS RDS Endpoint. When you create your RDS PostgreSQL database you need to copy and paste it into the C#.NET connection string. Once again, I thank you good people for validating the syntax of the connecting string for AWS RDS.